# How can I get a table-row that is two rows further down?

Tags: jquery

I have a reference to a table-row; how can I locate the row that is two-rows further down from this one, using jQuery?

Comment: What kind of row? Div? Table? ?? Post a code example and you'll probably get an answer with a working code sample in a few minutes.

Comment: You shouldn't be adding tags to your SO title...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are dealing with a `<tr>`:

```
$(row).next().next();
```